# Upload/download Image issue android + PHP + Base64

Tags: php, android, json, bitmap, base64

hello there I have an issue with displaying an image on an imageButton that I uploaded to my server. I can't figure out what is my mistake !

here is a short idea for what I'm doing when uploading :
Bitmap Image -> Base64 encoded to string -> upload string to server -> write string to file

a short idea for what I'mg doing when downloading:
read string from file -> put in JSON -> receive in Android -> Base64 decode to byte array-> decode byte array to Bitmap -> post to ImageButton

java code:

```
            //Storing image string
            if(scaledBitmap == null){
               bitMapPartyPicture = ((BitmapDrawable)partyPicture.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            }else{
               bitMapPartyPicture = scaledBitmap;
            }
            String imageString = jsonParser.encodeImage(bitMapPartyPicture);

//Encoding the Image
public String encodeImage(Bitmap image){
    Bitmap bitmap = image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
    Log.d("Image Base64",stream.toString());
    String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return image_str;
}

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,List<NameValuePair> params) {
//Upload Image
            try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://whatever.com/addProfilePic.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                is.reset();
                is.close();
            }catch(Exception e){

                  System.out.println("Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            }
        //Dealing with JSON Object
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            Log.d("JSON Object", json);
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
}



//Download Image
public byte[] downloadImage(String url,List<NameValuePair> imgName) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] ImageBytes = new byte[1024];
    String ImageString = null;
    byte[] DecodedImage = new byte[1024];
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(imgName));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        int LinesValue = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
            LinesValue++;
        }

        json = sb.toString();
        Log.d("Lines",Integer.toString(LinesValue));
        Log.d("JSON Object", json);
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        ImageString = jObj.getString("Image_Decoded");
        ImageBytes = ImageString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        is.close();

    }
    catch(IOException t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DecodedImage = Base64.decode(ImageString ,Base64.DEFAULT);

    return DecodedImage;
}
```

PHP Uploading side:

```
$image = $_POST['image'];// name of uploaded image
    $user  = $_POST['user'];
    $image_name = $_POST['imageName'];
    $file = null;
    $filePath = "photos/" . $user;


    $homeDir = "/home/a1400606/public_html/";
    if (!file_exists($homeDir.$filePath)) {
        mkdir($filePath, 0777);
    }
    if($image_name == 'partyPicture'){
        $file = fopen('partyPicture', 'w');
        fwrite($file, $image);
        fclose($file);

    }else if ($image_name == 'profilePicture'){
        $file = fopen('profilePicture', 'w');
        fwrite($file, $image);
        fclose($file);

    }else{
        $response["Error:"] = "Error";
    }

    if(rename(addslashes("$homeDir"."partyPicture"),addslashes( "$homeDir$filePath"."/partyPicture"))){
        $response["File Moved:"] = "Yes";
    }else {
        $response["File Moved:"] = "No";
    }
```

PHP Downloading side:

```
$image = "partyPicture";// name of uploaded image
    $user  = "xxxx";
    $filePath = "photos/" . $user."/";
    $homeDir = "/home/a1400606/public_html/";
    if (!file_exists(addslashes($homeDir.$filePath.$image))) {
        $response["Found File"] = "File doesn't exist";
    }else{
        $response["Found File"] = "File exist in directory";
        $imgstr=fread(fopen($homeDir.$filePath.$image,"r"),filesize($homeDir.$filePath.$image));
        $response["Image_Decoded"] = $imgstr;
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Posting image to ImageButton:

```
        byte[] bytesArray = new byte[1024];
        bytesArray = json.downloadImage(DOWNLOAD_IMAGE_URL, params);
        ImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytesArray, 0,bytesArray.length);
        if(ImageBitmap == null){
            InputStream is= new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesArray);
            ImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        }
        CreateImageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(ImageBitmap);
```

catLog for Uploading:

```
05-22 00:29:43.874: D/Image Base64(7530): ??????JFIF????????????????C??????C????p0"??????????????????????????   
05-22 00:29:43.874: D/Image Base64(7530): ???????????}??!1AQa"q2???#B??R??$3br? 
05-22 00:29:43.874: D/Image Base64(7530): %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????  
05-22 00:29:43.874: D/Image Base64(7530): ?????????w??!1AQaq"2?B????    #3R?br?
05-22 00:29:43.874: D/Image Base64(7530): $4?%?&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????{<1$?'?r_?O]???`????(,J?_?:?8?R;S????#????????Uy]?lU?FN?s??O??n????  E?gk?:I???S?eI?K?^>???V??~??o??A??$g????s?8?$?k??e?
?>e?~?Ons?g=A#?d?rD??6?1?@'???9??????j?^U?%???I???~?????r?F?????m????_]|?W$????v???E?&?w??zl??=?w3?x?M??QlA$???89??????1o"?Je`????y??}3?=??:??%??0%?c???    ?NFsY?q?D?,RQwI?{?]5???cw}O??$$?2??t???z]??[??hs-?mA??pH??b?C?????W?????$?G.$?????r9??[\Gg<A?v@&??Q?+?$`??n? ?^????A{??o????
05-22 00:29:43.874: D/Image Base64(7530): Ibs?#??>lj????'h?Z2\???}?V???B?9?9???Z&?U??-??x??{???<^??YA?6????\?V??U&ge??r[????'?CWmu??\y?A@?1o??I?B????$??u???^?ti>?:??(??{pS?O?Ms?E????????o?n??NthQ?????K???Z??????>????    ?p?z{??yl??$?X?*\H???t96~?#?-\k2??q}:???G??Sk:?z?x?rI??????r???v?`?y??9??e? 9VvW?m???r??????a9jNrVR?6?g)>f?n???k?4??$?1???g??'$?.?$U=0?;?>???tq?z??n???_S?lc ?????9-?K?$a????9?L~??^?,????IY-uWVM???K=[J???S??r?:i?Y^???????j?Wi$n??BG^XpA?P3?y??'???]NP?
?A??x??????,J?8u%?.?G_|{??&'<?9?????}J?$???kF?ww????%m???S?????????????????\?F=?I;H?=9???5??j??G?n??K7a???y!N}9??????$`?|z?'?p??w?????(?9??8??'????J??Vzn?{O7????B??)k?\???D?????{$./???????c?hk??\c?V?y?=3??3?.>P9????_? ?5v?$I
???`??z?:??I&????(?(%??G???Os????v?Q_?4????u??h?8??f)??px?\~G???kU??FDd??,?8?=3?p20
_??H??;[????}y??O$f?Ymf.???o?N??I???o?
05-22 00:29:43.874: D/Image Base64(7530): ????n|?o????????]??fn?fbF9??[8?? ??]B?]HnH?@i9?^?????????? ?}??t?=??v??*??S?Ts?9?}3?;????T?|??[E??????Wf??g   Mj?IZ???}??}t????Z`e?99??z??????5?!??&p2x???<????$?$
05-22 00:29:43.874: D/Image Base64(7530): ???|?Q???)-???????lc3:?0???N2zq??O??pZ?_??%4?i?/]?iwV?????;?????+?????
05-22 00:29:44.134: D/Address(7530): 567 Beaverbrook Ct
05-22 00:29:44.134: D/PostalCode(7530): E3B
05-22 00:29:44.134: D/City(7530): Fredericton
05-22 00:29:44.134: D/Date Format(7530): 22-5-2014
05-22 00:29:44.134: D/StartDate(7530): 22-5-2014
05-22 00:29:44.134: D/EndDate(7530): 22-5-2014
05-22 00:29:44.134: D/GeoAddress(7530): [Address[addressLines=[0:"567 Beaverbrook Ct",1:"Fredericton, NB E3B",2:"Canada"],feature=567,admin=New Brunswick,sub-admin=null,locality=Fredericton,thoroughfare=Beaverbrook Ct,postalCode=E3B,countryCode=CA,countryName=Canada,hasLatitude=true,latitude=45.9537013,hasLongitude=true,longitude=-66.646423,phone=null,url=null,extras=null]]
05-22 00:29:44.754: I/Choreographer(7530): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-22 00:29:46.614: I/System.out(7530): Error in http connection java.io.IOException
05-22 00:29:48.874: D/JSON Object(7530):        {"File Moved:":"Yes","ImageString":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB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
```

Catlog for Downloading:

```
05-22 00:30:58.664: D/Lines(7530): 1
05-22 00:30:58.694: D/JSON Object(7530):        {"Found File":"File exist in directory","Image_Decoded":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB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\nx195tdJsLWH7TCwYkDI5ORlvm7+o6\/mSWrUh0+61JlR
05-22 00:30:58.804: I/dalvikvm(7530): Jit: resizing JitTable from 8192 to 16384
05-22 00:30:59.134: D/bytesArray(7530): [B@423fc2e0
```

Comment: Logcat?  Errors thrown?  Data received?

Comment: I added the catlog ... there is no errors ... but it shows the sanded and received data

Comment: Why are you doing `ImageBytes = ImageString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));`?  More on-topic is that those addslashes are never being stripped.  Are they serving some purpose?

Comment: they have no use actually... they are there because I was trying to figure out what was the problem... however, I took them off... still nothing changed same input same output

Comment: @NW52 there is an error, it says "Error in http connection java.io.IOException"

Comment: Dont worry about that one .... The file completely move to the server otherwise i wont get a response

Comment: also, it's because there is an exit() function in my PHP file ... that means it cut the connection but it's not an error it's an info (I/)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in storing data in file. and also you dont give file extension in server side so it create garbage file. check it and give .jpg or .png with file name.. i hope this will help you..

Comment: given it .jpeg or not ... it can't recognize it as an image either in the server or the app

Answer (score 0):

Though the reply is late but it might help someone..

You are encoding the image in android to base64 before uploading which is right

but u failed to decode it at php side before saving it as image..

```
<?php
    $image = base64_decode($_POST['image']);// decoding the uploaded image
    $user  = $_POST['user'];
    $image_name = $_POST['imageName'];
    $file = null;
    $filePath = "photos/" . $user;
```

Hope it helps..